# jquery trigger table row click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample Code:

```
<table class="grid">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="unit_floor_plan_preview">click me &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td class="unitNumber"><span>Unit 1</span></td>
        <td class="unitStatus">Open</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td class="unitNumber"><span>Unit 2</span></td>
        <td class="unitStatus">Sold</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am able to get the row index of the row selected to get the exact column data.

```
tr = $('.grid').find('tr');

tr.bind('click', function(event) {

    unitNo = $(this).find("td.unitNumber span").html(); 
    alert(unitNo);


});
```

The above tr click event  is fine.

**My problem** now is how to trigger this tr binding event when clicking the anchor link `<td><a href="#" id="unit_floor_plan_preview">Show map &nbsp;</a></td>`within the table row?

> **Goal:** 
>   *To get first the `unitNo` (processed on tr.bind click event) before processing the rest of the code on anchored link?*

I tried to duplicate the tr click function within the anchor link click event but got ***undefined*** value on unitNo. See my code:

```
$('a[id^="unit_floor_plan_preview"]').bind('click',function() {
    var tr = $('.grid').find('tr');
    unitNo = $(this).find("td.unitNumber span").html();  

    alert('From link: ' + unitNo);

});
```

**test code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/VjkML/29/

Comment: The problem here is order of operations from event bubbling. The link will always come before the row click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
unitNo = tr.find("td.unitNumber span").html();
```

To:

```
unitNo = $(this).find("td.unitNumber span").html();
```

In `$('a[id^="unit_floor_plan_preview"]').bind('click'` You try to find `"td.unitNumber span"` within `$(this)`. The problem is, `this` refers to the link clicked on, thus you'll never find anything!

---

FYI, you could easily rewrite that ENTIRE statement as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", '.grid tr, a[id^="unit_floor_plan_preview"]', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // will prevent double click events from link being clicked within row
    var unitNo = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").find(".unitNumber span").text()); // trim to remove end space, closest gets closest parent of selected type
    if (e.target.tagName == "A") alert('From link: ' + unitNo);
    else alert(unitNo);
});
```

## Example

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to bind the event only to your `tr` and use the `event.target` to check if it is tr or any other element that was clicked. This way your click event will not be duplicated.

This should work

```
var unitNo;
var tr;

tr = $('.grid').find('tr');
tr.bind('click', function (event) {

    if ($(event.target).is('tr')) {
        // If it is a tr that is clicked then just use find
        unitNo = $(this).find("td.unitNumber span").html();
    } else {
        // If not tr find the closest tr and then find the element
        unitNo = $(this).closest('tr').find("td.unitNumber span").html();
    }
    alert(unitNo);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjkML/33/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var unitNo;
var tr = $('.grid').find('tr');
$('a[id^="unit_floor_plan_preview"]').on('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    unitNo = $(this).closest('tr').find("td.unitNumber span").html();  
    alert('From link: ' + unitNo);
});
tr.on('click', function(event) {
    unitNo = $(this).find("td.unitNumber span").html(); 
    alert(unitNo);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VjkML/35/)**

With the link you need to go up the DOM to the row (via `.closest()`), then use `.find()` to go back down the same row to find the span you want to get the Unit value.